# Need to understand the difference between stageDependencies and dependencies in Azure Devops Pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a pipeline that sets up some variables in the first stage and then in the second stage it uses one of those variables to retrieve a user token from an identity provider.

```yaml
# main.yml
stages:
- stage: DetermineEnvironment
  jobs:
  - job: GetVariables
    displayName: 'Set Working Environment Variables'
    pool:
      name: $(poolName)
    steps:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      name: SetVariables
      displayName: 'Set Working Environment Variables'
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          if ('$(ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT)' -eq 'Development') {
            Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=MongoDBConnectionString;isOutput=true;issecret=true]$(Development-MongoDBConnectionString)"
            Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=TelemetryConnectionString;isOutput=true;issecret=true]$(Development-TelemetryConnectionString)"
            Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=DatabaseName;isOutput=true]$(devDatabaseName)"
            Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ViewId;isOutput=true]$(devViewId)"
          } else {
            Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=MongoDBConnectionString;isOutput=true;issecret=true]$(Production-MongoDBConnectionString)"
            Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=TelemetryConnectionString;isOutput=true;issecret=true]$(Production-TelemetryConnectionString)"
            Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=DatabaseName;isOutput=true]$(prodDatabaseName)"
            Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ViewId;isOutput=true]$(prodViewId)"
          }
          Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ServiceAccountPassword;isOutput=true;issecret=true]$(ServiceAccountPassword)"
          Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Environment;isOutput=true]$(ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT)"
          Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=FileName;isOutput=true]$(id)"
          Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=AccountId;isOutput=true]$(AccountId)"
          Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=AccountName;isOutput=true]$(AccountName)"
          Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=CloudProvider;isOutput=true]$(CloudProvider)"
        workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
        pwsh: true
- stage: DeployAzure
  dependsOn:
  - DetermineEnvironment  condition: eq(variables['CloudProvider'], 'Azure')
  jobs:
  - job: GetServiceAccount
    pool:
      name: $(poolName)
    variables:
      password: $[ stageDependencies.DetermineEnvironment.GetVariables.outputs['SetVariables.ServiceAccountPassword'] ]
    steps:
    - template: get-sa-token.yml
      parameters:
        Username: $(serviceAccount)
        Password: $(password)
  - job: OutputToken
    dependsOn: GetServiceAccount
    pool:
      name: $(poolName)
    variables:
      SaToken: $[ dependencies.GetServiceAccount.outputs['GetSaToken.SaToken'] ]
    steps:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      name: SetVariables
      displayName: 'Set Working Environment Variables'
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          write-host "SaToken: $(SaToken)"
        workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
        pwsh: true
```

Here is the template that I call

```yaml
# get-sa-token.yml
parameters:
- name: Username
  type: string
- name: Password
  type: string

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  env:
    SaUsername: ${{ parameters.Username }}
    SaPassword: ${{ parameters.Password }}
  displayName: 'Get Service Account Credentials'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $IdentityServer = 'https://internal.corp/token'
      $body = (ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100 @{
          auth = @{
            'AUTH:domain'   = @{
              name = 'corp'
            }
            passwordCredentials = @{
              username = $env:SaUsername
              password = $env:SaPassword
            }
          }
        })
      $IdentToken = Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri $IdentityServer -ContentType 'application/json' -Body $body
      $token = $IdentToken .access.token.id
      write-host $token
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=SaToken;isOutput=true;issecret=true]$token"
  name: GetSaToken
```

I pass the password into the template using stageDependencies, and in my logged output of the template I can see the token is generated. But when I attempt to consume that output in a variable in a job in the same staga as the template call, it is empty. In the debug log on the run I see the following when it attempts to run the output script

```
##[debug]INPUT_SCRIPT: 'write-host "SaToken: "'
```

Looking at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/deployment-jobs?view=azure-devops#support-for-output-variables) it appears my refernces are correct

```yaml
    variables:
      password: $[ stageDependencies.DetermineEnvironment.GetVariables.outputs['SetVariables.ServiceAccountPassword'] ]


    variables:
      SaToken: $[ dependencies.GetServiceAccount.outputs['GetSaToken.SaToken'] ]
```

Comment: Indentation is a PITA, the changes suggested by Miao actually did work, and the code above should function as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change two lines in your yaml files.

First, in `main.yml`, you are using this

```
variables:
  SaToken: $[ dependencies.GetServiceAccount.outputs['GetServiceAccount.GetSaToken.SaToken'] ]
```

According to [Use outputs in a different job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#use-outputs-in-a-different-job), it should be

```
variables:
  SaToken: $[ dependencies.GetServiceAccount.outputs['GetSaToken.SaToken'] ]
```

The stage name `GetServiceAccount` is not needed.

Second, in `get-sa-token.yml`, you named the powershell task as `GetSaToken`. However, you added extra spaces before `name: GetSaToken`, which causing it becomes a line in the powershell Script. Please remove the extra spaces.

[image]

After the above steps, you will get the result:

[image]

Comment: I"m not sure what the difference is between your setup and mine, but making the changes suggested did not yield the same results for me.

Comment: Miao, I'm happy to reach out over email if you send me your address, I've been stuck on this step longer than I care to admin.

Answer (score 0):

`dependencies` are inter-job dependencies. `stageDependencies` are inter-stage dependencies. [The documentation states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#stage-to-stage-dependencies):

> The context is called dependencies for jobs and stages and works much like variables. If you refer to an output variable from a job in another stage, the context is called stageDependencies.

Note that for a stage to be dependent on another stage, you need to specify `dependOn`: to establish the dependency.

```yaml
stages:
- stage: DetermineEnvironment
- stage: DeployAzure
  dependsOn:
  - DetermineEnvironment
```

Comment: if you look at the code provided, SetVariables is a job within the same stage as GetServiceAccount. Adding the stage dependency doesn't really do anything. I modified the code with your change and there was still no output in debug.